# How to send view to Google Analytics with Android View Pager + ActionBar tabs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, google-analytics, android-actionbar

I use ViewPager and ActionBar tabs to display data to user and I also want to send current screen to Google Analytics.

But I have problem because ActionBar tabs work in way that they are loading data for current and next fragment, so in Google Analytics Real Time I get displayed only next fragment.

For each fragment in ActionBar tabs I send data to Google Analytics like this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    // Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts & uncaught exceptions
    // etc.
    // Get tracker.
    Tracker t = ((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication())
            .getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

    // Set screen name
    t.setScreenName(screenName);

    // Send a screen view.
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    super.onStart();
}
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried moving tracking to the `ViewPager` where the tabs get switched?

Answer (score 6):

I've found that checking the combination of `getUserVisibleHint()` and `isResumed()` within each fragment before sending the GA screenview event works. Overriding `setUserVisibleHint(boolean)` and `onResume()` ensures that the screen view event is sent regardless of the order in which they are called.

This solution solves the issue with using `ViewPager.setOnPageChengeListener` where the initial fragment doesn't get `onPageSelected` called.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
  super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
  publishScreenViewEvent();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  publishScreenViewEvent();
}

private void publishScreenViewEvent() {
  // Only publish if this fragment is visible to the user and the fragment has been resumed.
  // setUserVisibleHint may be called before onResume and before this fragment is injected.
  // onResume may be called before setUserVisibleHint because this fragment is in a ViewPager that
  // caches the next and previous fragment by calling onResume before the fragment is visible
  if (getUserVisibleHint() && isResumed()) {
    // Send GA screenview event here
  }
}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. It works brilliant!

Comment: This fails when screen is rotated and when onResume() is called first. Causes duplicate calls

Comment: @sha any suggestion on how to solve the rotation issue?

Comment: @jenglert Not yet. Got no time atm :( . But have an idea to save the userVisiblity in onSavedStateInstance() and use that as a marker to stop duplicate calls. Let me know if it works or if you find something better.

Comment: @jenglert Not yet. Got no time atm :( . But have an idea to save the userVisiblity in onSavedStateInstance() and use that as a marker to stop duplicate calls. Let me know if it works or if you find something better.

Answer (score 0):

I solved thus problem this way:
1. When my activity starts I place

```
Utils.sendGAScreenName("Highlights", this);
ActivityProducts_.intent(this).start();
```

This help me handle opening of first tab.

2.In ActivityProducts i defined `onPageChangeListener()` method

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
@Override

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        //Log.d("OnPageSelected " + position);
        switch (position)
        {
            case TAB_HIGHLIGHTS:
                Utils.sendGAScreenName("Highlights", ActivityProducts.this);
                break;
            case TAB_APPLICATIONS:
                Utils.sendGAScreenName("LT Brands", ActivityProducts.this);
                break;
            case TAB_PRODYCT_TYPE:
                Utils.sendGAScreenName("Product Type", ActivityProducts.this);
                break;
            case TAB_ALL_PRODUCTS:
                Utils.sendGAScreenName("All Products", ActivityProducts.this);
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For me, this was not invoked when the viewpager was just created and showed the first page. Only when manually changing the pages.